# Alpine indexing for long time

Tags: email, alpine-mail

I have alpine 2.0 installed and a gmail IMAP mailbox configured.
Every time I open alpine it starts to index and sort the mailbox which takes around 1 minute.
Also whenever I perform search using Whereis, it takes a long time.
Is this normal?

I am guessing that the folders are not indexet properly, or not stored offline.
my inbox is set as:

```
{imap.gmail.com/novalidate-cert/ssl/user=user@gmail.com}INBOX
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to check the box "Thread Sorts by Arrival" (under the menu "Message Index Preferences") in your configuration setting.

Also check "Arrival" in the menu "Sort Key" in your configuration settings.

Concerning your second question if your folders have a huge number of emails or your connection to your email server is slow, it is normal that the search take time.

Comment: thank you for your help. this seems to have solved the problem. regarding the search: the connection shouldn't be slow, its a standard gmail connection. is there some way to store the messages on my computer and continuously update it? then the search would be performed on my computer